# Dynamically adding contents to stackpanel in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Am trying to add Set of labels and images in a stackpanel in code behind.And finally am attaching that stackpanel to particular column of a grid control.My expected output should be like

```
<image><label>
```

combination

but my output is like it displays the label in first column of grid and the image in the next column.(I was not able to add the snapshots since i dont have enough reputations)

XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="Ping.MainWindow" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" Icon="F:\ChatApplication\Ping\Ping\Images\title.ico" Cursor="Pen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Ping - Connected by alphabets" Height="450" Width="750" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"  >
<Grid Name="grid_window">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>

    <TabControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="tab_control" BorderBrush="Cornsilk" BorderThickness="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="419" Margin="227,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="515">
        <TabItem Header="Home" BorderBrush="Green"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

code behind

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DBCoding dbobj = new DBCoding();
        //Contains names {"Dhivi","Walle"}
        List<string> online = new List<string>();

        online = dbobj.onlineUsers();
        StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
        myStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        foreach (var item in online)
        {
            Image myImage = new Image();
            myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("F:\\ChatApplication\\Ping\\Ping\\Images\\visible.png"));
            myImage.Width = 10;
            myImage.Height = 10;
            //myImage.Margin = new Thickness(-10,0,-80,0);
            myImage.Height = 10;
            Label user = new Label();
            user.Content = item.ToString();
            myStackPanel.Children.Add(myImage);
            myStackPanel.Children.Add(user);
        }
        grid_window.Children.Add(myStackPanel);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(myStackPanel, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(myStackPanel, 0);

    }
```

Can anybody tell me the solution.

Comment: it is not clear from the question what you want

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to have one image/label pair per row..?

Comment: Yes i need to have a pair.I got it by using two stackpanels.But one more doubt is i need to have a MouseDoubleClick event for the dynamically created labels.Can anyone help me ?

Comment: There should be a MouseDoubleClick event on the label: user.MouseDoubleClick += handler

Comment: Also, may I suggest that you check out data binding and DataTemplates. That stuff would be much more neat and practical by doing most of it in xaml!

Comment: user.MouseDoubleClick += Label_MouseDoubleClick_1(user,new MouseEventArgs());    i tried this.But its showing error for me.

Comment: @Chris can you please tell me the syntax

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. You need an `ItemsControl` for this.

Comment: Try just user.MouseDoubleClick += Label_MouseDoubleClick_1;

Comment: Thank you..I was trying tricky combinations

Answer (score 1):

Here's how your code should look like, using data binding, an `ItemsControl` and a `DataTemplate`:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Ping.MainWindow" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" Icon="F:\ChatApplication\Ping\Ping\Images\title.ico" Cursor="Pen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Ping - Connected by alphabets" Height="450" Width="750" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"  >
<Grid Name="grid_window">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>

    <TabControl Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="tab_control" BorderBrush="Cornsilk" BorderThickness="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="419" Margin="227,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="515">
        <TabItem Header="Home" BorderBrush="Green"/>
    </TabControl>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <DockPanel>
                      <!-- You really should add the image as a resource to the project -->
                      <Image Source="F:\ChatApplication\Ping\Ping\Images\visible.png" 
                             Width="10" Height="10" />
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                  </DockPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DBCoding dbobj = new DBCoding();
    List<string> online = dbobj.onlineUsers();
    DataContext = online;
}
```